# Create instance of wrapper class in lightning Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-controller

I want to use wrapper list in Lightning component

want to add row dynamically in list

but My controller fails at adding list element on init in a lightning controller

**Note: I want to add row element in component controller only**

this is my wrapper class

```
public class RPWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled public Rotation_Pair__c rpRec{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public List<Rotation_Detail__c> listRD{get;set;}
        public RPWrapper(){
            rpRec = new Rotation_Pair__c();
            listRD = new List<Rotation_Detail__c>();
        }
    }
```

Component Attribute defined

```
<aura:attribute name="rpWrapper" type="BulkPortPair_Controller.RPWrapper[]"/>  
<aura:attribute name="rpWrapperInstance" type="BulkPortPair_Controller.RPWrapper" />
```

Controller

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.createObjectData(component, event, "1");
    },
```

Helper

```
({
    createObjectData: function(component, event, noRows) {

        var dealId  = component.get("v.recordId");
            console.log("v.action"+ component.get("v.rpWrapper"));

            var RowItemList = component.get("v.rpWrapper");
            var rpWrapperInstance = component.get("v.rpWrapperInstance");
            for (var indexVar = 1; indexVar <= parseInt(noRows); indexVar++) {
                var rpRec = 
                RowItemList.push(rpWrapperInstance);
            }
            component.set("v.rpWrapper", RowItemList);
        },
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no code other than what you show is involved, defaulting the attribute to an empty array should fix the problem:

```
<aura:attribute
        name="rpWrapper"
        type="BulkPortPair_Controller.RPWrapper[]"
        default="[]"
        />
```

and there is a similar problem with the instance:

```
<aura:attribute
        name="rpWrapperInstance" 
        type="BulkPortPair_Controller.RPWrapper"
        default="{}"
        />
```

Comment: Or using a default value in the controller: `var RowItemList = component.get("v.rpWrapper") || []`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, we can use 'Object'

```
<aura:attribute
    name="rpWrapperInstance" 
    type="Object"
    default="{}"
    />
```